# IF-THEN Statement used with grep not fuctioning in UNIX Script

Tags: unix, if-statement, ksh

I have posted the same code for another question recently. I was helped with that but when trying to implement an If-Then statement, it returned erroneous results. So within this topic I will have 2 questions.

**First Question:**
When performing a search within a file, how do you implement the search so uppercase or lower case has no basis on returning the desired record?

**Second Question:**
In my If-Then statement no matter what I type it shows the else part of the If-Then Statement. For example, the name Smith is in the file, but no matter what I type "Smith" or "smith" yields the same result as "echo "Error: $last_name is not in file"".

**Additionally:**
This has to be written in korn shell programming.

The code is as follows:

```
#Gather search parameter
            read last_name
            if grep -Fxq "$last_name" $1
            then
                while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 rest ; do
                    case "$c1" in
                        "$last_name" )
                            echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nCity: $c3\nState: $c4\nClass: $c5\nSemester Enrolled: $c6\nYear First Enrolled: $c7\n\n"
                        ;;
                    esac
                done < $1
            else
                echo "Error: $last_name is not in file"
            fi
        ;;
```

Any insight into the coding of this would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

**User Input 1**

User input: Smith

Expected Output: 
Last Name: Smith
First Name: John
    ....

Actual Output:

Error: Smith is not in file

**User Input 2**

User input: smith

Expected Output:

Error: smith is not in file

Actual Output:

Error: smith is not in file

Comment: Ok changed the grep -Fxq to grep -Fiq it still won't pull up the Smith record if I keep it all lower case such as smith. However, inputting "Smith" will pull up the file now as opposed to before it would give the error message. One thing that is odd is it will not display the error message if I put "smith" it just exits the case statement.

Comment: That's because your grep search is case insensitive, but the case string comparison is not. Please review my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using grep's `-x` option: your user input must exactly match a complete line. I assume you don't want this behaviour.

Use `-i` for case insensitivity

```
        read "last_name?Enter a last name: "

        matches=0
        grep -Fi "$last_name" "$1" |
        while IFS=: read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 rest; do
            echo -e "Last Name: $c1\nFirst Name: $c2\nCity: $c3\nState: $c4\nClass: $c5\nSemester Enrolled: $c6\nYear First Enrolled: $c7\n\n"
            ((matches++))
        done

        if (( matches == 0 )); then
            echo "Error: $last_name is not in file"
        fi
```

In this case, I'm looping over the grep output directly, assuming that more than one line may match

Of course, it's misleading to be searching for "last name" with grep -- I could enter a city or a year, or a colon, and grep could find a match. If you're interested in this line of thought, let me know.

To test for string equality of the first field, awk would be a good choice

```
read "last_name?Enter a last name: "

awk -v name="$last_name" '
    tolower($1) == tolower(name) {
        print "Last Name:", $1
        print "First Name:", $2
        print "City:", $3
        print "State:", $4
        print "Class:", $5
        print "Semester Enrolled:", $6
        print "Year First Enrolled:", $7
        matches++
    }
    END {if (matches == 0) print "No matches for:", name }
' "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn that worked good. I have to search by last name it is part of the instructions. This will help me implement other aspects of this program though so thanks.

Comment: Actually just ran into some unintended results. Again if I search for the smith record and I enter "sm", "ith", or any character within the string smith it comes up with the smith record. Is there a way to make it only display if it is smith, Smith, SMITH, or any combination not just certain characters. It wouldn't be that big of a deal except that when I input "s" then a different record all together displays.

Comment: That's what I cautioned in my last paragraph. You really want case insensitive string equality of the first field, right?

Comment: Yeah, ok I see what you meant in the last paragraph now. Yeah it keeps giving me records that only have a few of the chracters in it

Comment: I have the explicit instructions of no perl, awk, or arrays. I know this makes it difficult. However, I was doing some searching and I think I could use egrep in some way. I am still researching it.

Comment: `grep -i "^${last_name}:"` should anchor it sufficiently. The user can still enter a regular expression like `.*` that will cause false positive matches, but if you are forced to live with stupid restrictions, the client gets stupid programs.

Comment: Thanks the grep -I "^${last_name}:" worked perfectly